# Как поменять стили для тегов a и span?

Tags: html, css

В общем, есть несколько файлов css. У всех разные стили для `a, p, span, nav` и т.д. Как сделать, чтобы для определенного объекта или блока вытягивался отдельный стиль с определенного файлы? Например:

```
<div class="test1"><a>doroga domoy</a></div> и в <div class=test2"><a>doroga domoy</a></div>
```

, где в `тест1` дорога домой была шрифтом `20 пикселей` и черного цвета, а в `тест2` `40 пикселей` и красного цвета?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
.test1 a{
   font-size: 20px;
   color: #000;
}
.test2 a{
   font-size: 40px;
   color: #f00;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/bERAW/

задавайте class for a, span и др  и прописывайте стили для них в файле css